# PySide2 - change table header background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

What I have now is default QTableWidget. I only changed background color for rows with even indexes. I want to do the same for table headers.

[image]

What I tried - `self.horizontalHeaderItem(...).setBackgroundColor(QColor(...))` and `self.horizontalHeaderItem(...).setBackground(QBrush(...))` - fail.

What I tried next - `self.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("::section {" "background-color: lightblue; }")` - I managed to change background color. The problems are (1) I don't quite understand what this code actually is since I can't find it in the PySide2 documentation, (2) the code changes not only background but many header appearance features.

How can I change only header background? Or more generally - how to tune table header appearance in PySide2?

[image]

Comment: "I don't quite understand what this code actually is since I can't find it in the PySide2 documentation" - If you want to look up documentation, don't bother with pyside or pyqt, just look it up for qt itself, it's quite easy to convert whatever you see back into python :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I post what I learned in my quest for the answer - 2 possible solutions.

I guess the problem originates from some tangled mixture of `notImplemented`, `notDocumented`, `notExplained` issues with PySide2. I hope the situation will change for the better in the future. Now to the answer.

The problem may be solved like this (and may not):

```
plt = QPalette()
plt.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(128, 0, 0))
my_table_widget.horizontalHeader().setPalette(plt)
```

`QPalette` controls colors of widgets. But there is another layer of appearance control - style. I use PySide2 on Win10x64 so default style is `windowsvista` with 3 styles available in total: `fusion`, `windows`, `windowsvista`. `Windowsvista` style ignores most of the palette colors. So for this approach to work one should change the style of the whole application (or some widgets only?):

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
```

Another solution I came up with is (preferable for me):

```
my_table_widget.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet('''
    ::section {
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-style: flat;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        }''')
```

together with:

```
my_table_widget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

I guess this is a style sheet to tune button appearance. I don't quite understand the meaning of `section` word. Moreover, to use this approach one should use google and Qt5 documentation. How my table looks with the second solution applied:

[image]

Comment: I accepted my own answer since it looks like a viable way to handle the situation. Kinda. I guess. I will improve it if I find true solution to the problem.